# How to obtain transaction innerInstructions as Explorer shows?

Tags: transactions, instructions, versionedtransactions

I'm a bit confused about additional info in transaction. I need to parse it and handle information from the instruction, but i can't. And what confusing me more - explorer. Explorer knows everything. How to obtain the same amount of information about tx with web3.js?

For example: explorer does know about everything that happened and seems this instructions are inner instructions aswell...
[image]

So i getting info about tx from web3.js with `getTransaction`, or `getParsedTransaction` and there is nothing about! And even instruction data is null.

`innerInstructions: null`

```
instructions: [
    {
      accounts: [Array],
      data: '',
      programIdIndex: 4,
      stackHeight: null
    }
  ],
```

So how do i get all these? Or i missed something? Much appreciate for any info!

Here is original tx: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3FfZvpP57t9LTiF2YNs6tJfLnZL8jV6LcxnDdiWDdVaYnEzVpHuzNi8om8kVPvXJej1VvBrF7cLegnBCUTdaYs7y?cluster=testnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem was in `--enable-extended-tx-metadata-storage` on validator. Once we put this parameter all logs and innerInstructions are on their place.

Comment: oh thanks for sharing this! glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, Explorer is open source, so you can always go poke around and find how they do stuff--take a look h[ere](https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer/blob/31ca21e3197aeaa07308a4555aa3b80914361228/src/components/transaction/InstructionsSection.tsx#L79).

I'm able to get these inner instructions using `getTransaction`:

```
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, VersionedTransactionResponse } from "@solana/web3.js";

const SOLANA_CONNECTION: Connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('testnet'));
const TX_ID = '3FfZvpP57t9LTiF2YNs6tJfLnZL8jV6LcxnDdiWDdVaYnEzVpHuzNi8om8kVPvXJej1VvBrF7cLegnBCUTdaYs7y';
const getTxInfo = async (txId: string) => {
    let result: VersionedTransactionResponse | null = await SOLANA_CONNECTION.getTransaction(txId, {commitment: 'finalized', maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0});
    if (!result || !result.meta) return;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.meta.innerInstructions));
    return result;
}
getTxInfo(TX_ID);
```

Results logged:

```
[
    {
        "index": 0,
        "instructions": [
            {
                "accounts": [
                    3
                ],
                "data": "84eT",
                "programIdIndex": 5,
                "stackHeight": 2
            },
            {
                "accounts": [
                    0,
                    1
                ],
                "data": "11119os1e9qSs2u7TsThXqkBSRVFxhmYaFKFZ1waB2X7armDmvK3p5GmLdUxYdg3h7QSrL",
                "programIdIndex": 2,
                "stackHeight": 2
            },
            {
                "accounts": [
                    1
                ],
                "data": "P",
                "programIdIndex": 5,
                "stackHeight": 2
            },
            {
                "accounts": [
                    1,
                    3
                ],
                "data": "6TCo3bcH9EjTXRbnDMBX1jEoxEJUyquc5W9nn5AwJcU5m",
                "programIdIndex": 5,
                "stackHeight": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: thank you. hm, that's really really strange... because i still obtain wrong data...

Comment: are you connected to the correct cluster? (in this case, testnet)

check that you have the latest solana-web3.js installed in your application

Comment: nah, all libs are updated to the latest version, problem was (and still is) in our testnet validator. devopses raised our own instance. And seems that's why we dont have innerInstructions and logMessages in our transactions. Because when im request the same tx from solana's testnet everything is fine. I guess by default personal validator doesnt provide this info.